# Relativistic 2-body problem with instantaneous Colomb force

Tags: special-relativity, coulombs-law

**Setup**

Assume that we have two (isolated) massive and electrically charged particles, moving in the vacuum space, that interact through the *instantaneous* Coulomb force. I am an inertial observer and I want to build the equations of motion for each particle. Let ${{\mathbf{r}}_{i}}\left( t \right)$ be trajectory* of the particle with rest mass ${{m}_{i}}$ and electric charge ${{q}_{i}}$, and ${{\mathbf{F}}_{i}}\left( t \right)$ the force applied to that particle. Then, in my reference frame, the equations of motion for each particle would be:
$$\tfrac{d}{dt}{{\mathbf{p}}_{i}}\left( t \right)={{\mathbf{F}}_{i}}\left( t \right)$$
where ${{\mathbf{p}}_{i}}\left( t \right)\equiv {{m}_{i}}{{\gamma }_{i}}\left( t \right){{\mathbf{\dot{r}}}_{i}}\left( t \right)$, ${{\gamma }_{i}}\left( t \right)\equiv \gamma \left( {{v}_{i}}\left( t \right) \right)$ and ${{v}_{i}}\left( t \right)\equiv \left\| {{{\mathbf{\dot{r}}}}_{i}}\left( t \right) \right\|$.

${*}$ as it is observed in *my* reference frame, where $t$ is the reading of *my* clock

**The question**

Let, $\mathbf{r}\left( t \right)\equiv {{\mathbf{r}}_{1}}\left( t \right)-{{\mathbf{r}}_{2}}\left( t \right)$ and $K\equiv {{{q}_{1}}{{q}_{2}}}/{\left( 4\pi {{\varepsilon }_{0}} \right)}\;$. Which expression should I use for ${{\mathbf{F}}_{i}}\left( t \right)$? Possible candidates are:

1. the Coulomb force between two particles that are ${r}\left( t \right)$ far apart from each other, i.e.:
   $${{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left( t \right)=K\frac{1}{{{r}^{2}}\left( t \right)}\mathbf{\hat{r}}\left( t \right)=-{{\mathbf{F}}_{2}}\left( t \right)$$
2. the Coulomb force that takes into account the phenomenon of length contraction, i.e.:
   $${{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left( t \right)=K\frac{1}{{{\left( r\left( t \right){{\gamma }_{1}}\left( t \right) \right)}^{2}}}\mathbf{\hat{r}}\left( t \right)\quad ,\quad {{\mathbf{F}}_{2}}\left( t \right)=-K\frac{1}{{{\left( r\left( t \right){{\gamma }_{2}}\left( t \right) \right)}^{2}}}\mathbf{\hat{r}}\left( t \right)$$

If non of the above is true, which would be the correct expression? Let it be noted that we *disregard any retardation effects*.

**My intuition**

I would say with certainty that it is case 2., unless I had noticed the following:
$${{\mathbf{F}}_{1}}\left( t \right)+{{\mathbf{F}}_{2}}\left( t \right)=K\frac{1}{{{r}^{2}}\left( t \right)}\left( \frac{1}{\gamma _{1}^{2}\left( t \right)}-\frac{1}{\gamma _{2}^{2}\left( t \right)} \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}\left( t \right)=K\frac{1}{{{c}^{2}}{{r}^{2}}\left( t \right)}\left( v_{2}^{2}\left( t \right)-v_{1}^{2}\left( t \right) \right)\mathbf{\hat{r}}\left( t \right)$$
which, in general, implies that $\tfrac{d}{dt}\left( {{\mathbf{p}}_{1}}\left( t \right)+{{\mathbf{p}}_{2}}\left( t \right) \right)\ne 0$, unless $v_{1}^{2}\left( t \right)=v_{2}^{2}\left( t \right)$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

**More questions**

If my intuition is correct, then why, in general, is the total relativistic momentum not conserved? Is it because we neglected the retardation effects, and treated the problem semi-relativistically. Or is there a logical fallacy in the above considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Columb law (vetorial)
$$ \vec{E}(x,y,z) = \frac{e \vec{r}}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^3}, $$

Biot-Savart (vectorial + some calculus simplification from $ c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon \mu}}$)
$$ \vec{B}(x,y,z) = \frac{\mu_0 e (\vec{v} \times \vec{r}) }{4 \pi r^3} =  
\frac{(\vec{v} \times \vec{r}) q}{c^2 (4 \pi \epsilon_0  r^3)} = \frac{\vec{v} \times \vec{E}}{c^2} $$

The correct way to treat electromagnetism interaction in relativity is to use
electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$

$$ F^\mu_\nu = 
\left( \begin{matrix}
0 & -E_x/c & -E_y/c & -E_z/c \\
-E_x/c & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
-E_y/c & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
-E_z/c & -B_y & B_x & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right) ,
$$

Four-velocity vector
$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}},  d\tau = \frac{dt}{\gamma}$$

$$ U^\mu = \left ( 
\begin{matrix} 
\gamma c \\ 
\gamma v_x \\ 
\gamma v_y \\ 
\gamma v_z \\
\end{matrix}\right ) , $$

Relativistic "force" law

$$ \frac{d(m_{0}U^\mu)}{d\tau} = - e F^\mu_\nu U^\nu $$

Some notations
$$ \beta_x = \frac{v_x}{c} , \beta_x = \frac{v_y}{c} , \beta_z = \frac{v_z}{c} , \beta = \frac{v}{c}, v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2} $$

Lorentz Boost in arbitrary direction:
$$ \Lambda^\mu_\nu(v) = 
\left ( \begin{matrix}
\gamma    &  -\beta_x\gamma    &  -\beta_y\gamma   &   -\beta_z\gamma   \\
-\beta_x\gamma &   1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_x^2/\beta^2  &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_x\beta_y/\beta^2   &      (\gamma - 1)\beta_x\beta_z/\beta^2 \\
-\beta_y\gamma &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_y\beta_z/\beta^2     & 1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_y^2/\beta^2   &  (\gamma - 1)\beta_y\beta_z/\beta^2 \\
-\beta_z\gamma &    (\gamma - 1)\beta_z\beta_x/\beta^2    &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_z\beta_y/\beta^2    &   1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_z^2/\beta^2 \\
\end{matrix} \right ) $$
Lowering + uppering indexes
$$ \Lambda_\mu^\nu(v) = \eta_{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta} \Lambda^\alpha_\beta(v) $$
$$  \Lambda_\mu^\nu(v) = \left ( \begin{matrix}
\gamma    &  \beta_x\gamma    &  \beta_y\gamma   &   \beta_z\gamma   \\
\beta_x\gamma &   1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_x^2/\beta^2  &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_x\beta_y/\beta^2   &      (\gamma - 1)\beta_x\beta_z/\beta^2 \\
\beta_y\gamma &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_y\beta_z/\beta^2     & 1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_y^2/\beta^2   &  (\gamma - 1)\beta_y\beta_z/\beta^2 \\
\beta_z\gamma &    (\gamma - 1)\beta_z\beta_x/\beta^2    &   (\gamma - 1)\beta_z\beta_y/\beta^2    &   1 + (\gamma - 1)\beta_z^2/\beta^2 \\
\end{matrix} \right ) $$
Transformation of fields (we treat field as independent from source after generated - aka like a photon after being generated)
if $|\vec{v_{src}}| > 0$ then (src = source = "emitter", $v_{src}$ as seen by a rest observer)
$$ (F')^\mu_\nu = \Lambda^\mu_\alpha(v_{src}) \Lambda_\nu^\beta(v_{src}) F^\alpha_\beta $$

The full law:
$$ \frac{d(m_{0}U^\mu)}{d\tau} = - e (F')^\mu_\nu U^\nu $$

[image: Nicolae Barbulescu - Bazele Fizice ale Relativitatii Einsteiniene, 1975 - page 134]
(In this image: **the relativistic effect of precession** - similar to the precession of the perihelion of Mercury [as opposed to classical prediction which would've been a simple unique orbit])

PS: If you need to create a simulation of some sort I recommend you to use matrix(vectorial) calculus and not try to decompose(break/dismantle) tensors into simpler forms because it's for sure you'll end up making a sign/symbol mistake.

References (some):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism
- [A Boost in an Arbitrary Direction](http://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node52.html)
- [The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II - Lorentz Transformations of the Fields](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_26.html)
- Nicolae Barbulescu - Bazele Fizice ale Relativitatii Einsteiniene, 1975
- A.Einstein - The Meaning of Relativity, Sixth Edition

Comment: Interesting approach but, since the particles do not move inertially, I am kind of a skeptical regarding the right to use Lorentz boosts, so as to transist in a non-inertial frame.

Comment: Lorentz boost in Minkowski metric is just the solution of vector transformation  V^mu = partial(X^mu)/partial(X^nu)  V^nu aka Lambda = partial(X^mu)/partial(X^nu). This is special relativity. Check the references above - they are from good SR lectures

Comment: See also https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-033-relativity-fall-2006/lecture-notes/ especially look for "General Transformation Laws for E and B"

Comment: I absolutely agree with that. My objection is that Lorentz boosts are derived after postulating that "the laws of physics are the same in all *inertial* frames"

Comment: I can't lead you further, [because] I'm not a teacher. Perhaps someone else might also want to contribute with an answer that would clarify misleadings here and there. Sorry and thx :)

Comment: I thank you for your effort of providing a such extended and detailed answer